# new column containing minimum data from 2 other columns

Tags: r

I have a variable "drugstartdate.imp" which contains dates. I would like to create in R a new column, that contains the date from the columns "tpxdate.1","tpxdate.2","tpxdate.3",... thatis clostest do the date of the variable "drugstartdate.imp" .

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. In order to get adeqate support please see here <https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking>

Answer (score 0):

Select the columns of interest, loop over them with `sapply`, take the `abs`olute difference between them and the 'drugstartdate.imp' column, create a column index with `max.col`, `cbind` with row index to extract the value correspond to row/column index

```
nm1 <- c('tpxdate.1', 'tpxdate.2', 'tpxdate.3')
nm2 <-  "drugstartdate.imp"
j1 <- max.col(sapply(df1[nm1], function(x) -abs(x - df1[[nm2])), 'first')
df1[nm1][cbind(seq_len(nrow(df1)), j1)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot, I could create j1 but let's say that for row 1, I should consider the value of tpxdate.1, for row 2 the value from tpxdate.3,...how can I create now a new column that contains the value from tpxdate.1 in the first row, the value from tpxdate.3 in the second row,...?

Comment: @Dimitri What will be the value for row 4?

Comment: your suggested code indicates me that for row 1, I should consider the value of tpxdate.1, for row 2 the value from tpxdate.3,...So how can I create now a new column that contains the value from tpxdate.1 in the first row, the value from tpxdate.3 in the second row,...?

Comment: @Dimitri Can you please edit your post with a small reproducible example and expected output so that it is more clear

Comment: As you can see below, I have an example. I would like to add a new column, containing the values from "tpxdate.1" and "txpdate.2" that are closest to "drugstartdate.imp"

Answer (score 0):

| patid | drugstartdate.imp | tpxdate.1 | tpxdate.2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 80000263 | 2008-06-30 | 2008-06-30 | 2015-02-12 |
| 80000263 | 2008-07-07 | 2008-06-30 | 2015-02-12 |
| 80000263 | 2015-02-11 | 2008-06-30 | 2015-02-12 |